# Haskell type math problem

Tags: list, haskell, types

I'm haskell beginner. I try to write function that's will return penultimate list element.

I start so:

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> a
lastButOne list = if null list
           then 
                0
           else 
                length list
```

0 string i get error:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `Int'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for lastButOne :: [a] -> a
```

I understand it. But what can i do here? I don't know list type. What can i put here?

Thank you.

Comment: It isn't clear what you actually want to return. Would Maybe a make sense?

Comment: @Craig "The penultimate element"

Comment: Make the type signature to return an integer and not "a" which is type of the list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0 is of type int, so it won't work for all `a`. I would suggest instead to use `Maybe a` like so:

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> Maybe a
lastButOne [] = Nothing
lastButOne [x] = Nothing
lastButOne xs = Just $ list !! (length xs - 2)
```

Using guards:

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> Maybe a
lastButOne xs | length xs > 1 = Just $ list !! (length list - 2)
              | otherwise = Nothing
```

Using the MonadPlus instance of Maybe:

```
import Control.Monad (guard)

lastButOne :: [a] -> Maybe a
lastButOne list = guard (length list > 1) >> return (list !! (length list - 2))
```

In general, for any instance of MonadPlus:

```
import Control.Monad (guard)

lastButOne :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m a
lastButOne list = guard (length list > 1) >> return (list !! (length list - 2))
```

Although somewhere you will have to specify to the compiler that you want the result as a Maybe. Usually this will be type inferred because it will be passed to a function expecting a Maybe.

Please keep in mind that this runs in O(n). You probably don't want to be finding the penultimate element of a list... Why do you need to do this? At least consider using an array instead.

Comment: @delnan I was worried about !! and -, not function application.

Comment: @delnan Tested in ghci. Parentheses are required.

Comment: I'd avoid making/using a recursive call with `length` as that makes the operation `O(n^2)`.  Instead, try a pattern match like in bearzk's answer or use reverse: `lastButOne = listToMaybe . drop 1 . reverse`

Comment: @Thomas Its still O(n). What are you talking about? length is O(n), and I'm not using any explicit recursion. I also included a pattern match version; I have for versions of the same function in my answer... Naturally I admit that my solution is slower, since its probably recursing the list twice, but who cares when the real problem is the fact that he is using the wrong data structure for the algorithm at hand?

Comment: Re: "You probably don't want to be finding the penultimate element of a list" This is almost certainly one of a set of 99 basic problems that many people use when learning a new language, and not part of a performance critical application.

Comment: @John if you are doing it quite a lot, then you don't want to be using a list. It is a bottleneck to use O(n) where O(1) is clearly applicable. Why are you not storing this stuff in the front of the list, where you have O(1) access?

Comment: @monadic: because that is not what the problem asked.  Please see http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_Haskell_exercises problem #2 in particular.  The 99-problems were originally developed by Werner Hett as a teaching tool for Prolog they were then translated into Lisp and from there into most of the major languages including Haskell.  They begin with very simple list manipulation.  At this point in the set it is about learning the syntax, NOT about what performs best. Please read the problem set to understand why sorting the list is irrelevant at this level.

Comment: @monadic I don't know what I was thinking when I made that comment, but figure I must have misread your code.  In short, you are right and I wouldn't have said the same thing in my current frame of mind.

Comment: @John And its not my answer. Its a side comment.

Answer (score 4):

The signature says "This function takes a list with elements of any type, and returns a value of the same element all the elements of the list". The code, on the other hand, says "This function takes a list with elements of any type, and returns a number". The correct type signature for *that* would be `[a] -> Int`* ("This function takes a list with elements of any type, and returns a value of any type that's a `Num`").

But since you want to return the second-to-last element instead of the length of the list, the type signature is correct but the code isn't. You have to take some item from the list, or *somehow* (`error`, using a `Maybe` return type, using pattern matchign and just omitting clauses for those cases, returning `undefined :: a`) handle lists that don't have a second-to-last element because they have less than two elements.

(*) It would be `(Integral b) => [a] -> b` if the prelude `length` wasn't bent on giving out only `Int`s for performance.

Comment: That should be Integral b, not Num b, should it not?

Comment: @monadic: Would make sense - but `Data.List.genericLength` uses `Num` for some reason. I still changed it and added a note why it's `Int` in its current incarnation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also new to Haskell. I think your problem is the `0` in your code. I don't really know how to fix it, but here is my solution, hope it's helpful:

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> a

lastButOne [] = error "empty list"
lastButOne [x1] = error "only one element"
lastButOne [x1,x2] = x1
lastButOne (x:xs) = lastButOne xs
```

the function removes elements from beginning until there are 2 elements left, then the first of these two is the last-But-One.

Answer (score 1):

Ostentatious solution

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> a
lastButOne [] = error "empty list"
lastButOne [x] = x
lastButOne xs = head $ drop 1 $ reverse xs
```

Comment: `lastButOne = head . drop 1 . reverse` is nicer.